# How to use super in Pyglet in Window's subclass events?

Tags: python, events, super, pyglet

I want to subclass pyglet.window.Window, but this code throw me exceptions for super in on_draw() and in on_mouse_pressed()

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pyglet


class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *arguments, **keywords):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*arguments, **keywords)

    def on_draw(self):
        super(Window, self).on_draw()
        self.clear()

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        super(Window, self).on_key_press(symbol, modifiers)
        if symbol == pyglet.window.key.A:
            print "A"

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        super(Window, self).on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers)
        if button:
            print button


window = Window()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Whereas this code doesn't. Why it this? Is safe use super in Pyglet events?

The default on_draw() in pyglet.window.Window call flip() but I can't call on_draw() of pyglet.window.Window and I can't find where on_draw() is defined in Pyglet modules. Where is this defined and why I can't call on_draw() of pyglet.window.Window with super?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pyglet


class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *arguments, **keywords):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*arguments, **keywords)

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        super(Window, self).on_key_press(symbol, modifiers)
        if symbol == pyglet.window.key.A:
            print "A"

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        if button:
            print button


window = Window()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `on_draw` or `on_mouse_press` function defined for `pyglet.window.Window`, so you cannot call them.  In the base class, these only exist as registered event types, which means that when the window receives one of them through `dispatch_event()`, it will first check its event stack for a handler, then its own attributes for a function with a matching name.  If there is no match in either place, the event is ignored.  This is what allows you to define a handler directly as you did in your code, or by using a decorator outside the class to push a handler onto the stack (or both).

The `EventLoop` does dispatch an `on_draw` event to each window during every iteration, but `flip()` is called separately.

Source:

```
class EventLoop(event.EventDispatcher):
    # ...
    def idle(self):
        # ...
        # Redraw all windows
        for window in app.windows:
            if redraw_all or (window._legacy_invalid and window.invalid):
                window.switch_to()
                window.dispatch_event('on_draw')
                window.flip()
                window._legacy_invalid = False
```